# how to type a variable in FastApi-SwaggerUI with hyphen in its name?

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi, pydantic, uvicorn

If I send a request to this API:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class Response(BaseModel):
    var_name: str

@app.put("/", response_model=Response)
def simple_server(a: str):
    response = Response(var_name=a)
    return response
```

I get a response which this json file `{"var_name1": "a"}`. In addition, I get a very beautiful Swagger UI that illustrate the fields of response.

My question is, how can I get this json file `{"var-name1": "a"}` (this is with a hyphen instead of an underscore) with the same nice typing in Swagger docs?

Obviously, I cannot name the `var_name` attribute `var-name` in Response dataclass.

Comment: You can alias field names: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/#alias-precedence- so maybe `var_name: str = Field(..., alias='var-name')` does what you need?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Modify your pydantic object slightly:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class Response(BaseModel):
    var_name: str = Field(alias="var-name")

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
```

The `allow_population_by_field_name` option is needed to allow creating object with field name, without it you could instantiate it only with alias name.